# Can I activate an ability after part of a spell has resolved? (please read example)

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-stack

I made a [Phelddagrif](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phelddagrif) group hug deck with [Windfall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Windfall) as my win condition (obviously I would only use it in an emergency) and [Elixir of Immortality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elixir%20of%20Immortality).

So, I cast [Windfall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Windfall) with, say, 40 cards in my hand, the text says "Each player discards their hand, then draws an amount of cards equal to the greatest number of cards a player discarded this way". So, could I use [Elixir of Immortality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elixir%20of%20Immortality) after I discarded my hand, but before I drew 40 more cards? I know this sounds silly as I'd think that it wouldn't work, but if it does then I can do a lot more with my deck. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I cast a spell while another spell or ability is resolving?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8116/6692)

Comment: I would advise not mentioning cards, formats, and mechanics that are not relevant to the question. For example, the Phelddagrif card and the Commander format are irrelevant. Context is good when it directly supports the question, but Windfall and Elixir of Immortality could be played in Legacy, without Phelddagrif.

Comment: I realize "phelddagrif group hug deck" is not relative to the question, but what is a phelddagrif group hug deck?

Comment: It's basically a deck in EDH that is based around helping everyone so that you're not a target. Thanks for the quick reply, I'll format my questions better in the future

Comment: @PoorPinkus I wouldn't worry about it; sometimes it's hard to know whether the context is important or not, and it's better to provide too much than too little. (As long as it's not a ton to read through, which it definitely wasn't.) It didn't really help your question, but it also didn't really harm it.

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed, this little trick doesn't work. There are only two ways to activate an ability or cast a spell while another spell or ability is resolving, and your combo doesn't fall into either one:

1. If the spell/ability that's resolving lets a player pay mana, that player can activate mana abilities.
2. If the spell/ability currently resolving explicitly tells you to cast a spell or allows you to cast a spell, you can cast that spell. Even in this case, the newly cast spell waits on the stack until the current spell/ability finishes resolving.

> CR 608.2f If an effect gives a player the option to pay mana, he or she may activate mana abilities before taking that action. If an effect specifically instructs or allows a player to cast a spell during resolution, he or she does so by putting that spell on top of the stack, then continuing to cast it by following the steps in rules 601.2a–h, except no player receives priority after it's cast. The currently resolving spell or ability then continues to resolve, which may include casting other spells this way. No other spells can normally be cast and no other abilities can normally be activated during resolution.