# Sacrifice Question

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have two creatures and barrage of expendables on the battlefield. My opponent casts a spell with the effect: "Each opponent sacrifices a creature"
Can I choose to sacrifice creature 1, then before my opponent's spell resolves, sacrifice creature 1 as the cost for barrage of expendables, thus resulting in only having lost creature 1?

Comment: Well... It's not a perfect duplicate, since the sacrifice caused by Chainer's Edict* isn't strictly speaking a "cost". (*or whatever spell OP is talking about. AFAICT _no_ card contains the exact text "Each opponent sacrifices a creature" and nothing else)

Comment: Also http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5892/can-you-claim-a-double-sacrifice-bonus (but it's already marked as a dup of the final dup chosen here).

Comment: The way you've phrased this there's actually one thing worth mentioning that's left implicit in the other questions: when a spell says to sacrifice a creature, you choose the creature to sacrifice when the spell resolves. It's not like something that says "target creature" where you pick up front; you wait until something says to sacrifice and *then* choose. That means there's never any way to cheat out of it like this: as long as you have at least one creature, you're going to lose one.

Comment: This is also a near duplicate of [Can I cast a spell while another spell or ability is resolving?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8116/6692). You cannot begin resolving a spell by choosing a creature to sacrifice, then go do something else, and then finish resolving the spell. You have to resolve the spell all at once, and *then* you can do other stuff.